# Property will not serialize as XML attribute

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to serialize a class as XML and to have the properties be serialized as attributes of the class, rather than a nested node. I am using WebApi to automatically handle the serialization of the XML.

This is my class:

```
[DataContract (Namespace="", Name="AttributeTest")]
[Serializable]
public class AttributeTestClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("Property")]
    [DataMember]
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the output I am receiving (note that `Property1` is **not** an attribute in spite of it being decorated with `[XmlAttribute]`):

```
<AttributeTest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Property1>123</Property1>
</AttributeTest>
```

This is the output I want to receive:

```
<AttributeTest Property1="123" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</AttributeTest>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebApi but the output you receive looks like it's serialized using `DataContractSerializer`, not `XmlSerializer` which you would need. Check if this helps: http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.de/2013/02/xml-serialization-in-aspnet-web-api.html

Comment: @nodots: That did it, thank you. Please post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with WebApi but the output you receive looks like it's serialized using `DataContractSerializer`, not `XmlSerializer` which you would need. Check if adding the following to `Application_Start` in `Global.asax` helps:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(
    new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

(From http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.de/2013/02/xml-serialization-in-aspnet-web-api.html)